# How to search for a folder with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to search for a folder in a specific directory and subdirectorys.

I tried googling it, but didn't really find any usefull examples.

Comment: Have you looked at the `-recurse` switch on `Get-ChildItem`?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "keyword"}
```

I believe there's no dedicated cmdlet for searching files.

Edit in response to @Notorious comment:
Since Powershell 3.0 this is much easier, since switches `-Directory` and `-File` were added to `Get-ChildItem`. So if you want it short you've got:

```
ls c:\test *key* -Recurse -Directory
```

With command alias and tab-completion for switches it's a snap. I just missed that the first time.

Comment: For those less Powershell familiar, the expression '$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true' is the test for the current object being a folder.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Please see the edit for shorter version. Besides that popular commands usually have aliases you're familiar with from *nix or cmd, long command names system has it's advantages. You can easily grasp new module thanks to verb-noun convention, and find commands: `get-command -Noun item`; `Get-Command -Verb convertto`.

Comment: this makes no sense to me. Which part of `ls c:\test *key* -Recurse -Directory` do I replace with the directory name I want to find?

Comment: @Robin `*key*` is a filter for directory name that you expect to be somewhere in `c:\test`.

Comment: `-Directory` works only in newer versions of powershell. Also `Get-ChildItem == ls == gci` for any newbs

Answer (score 6):

Here is my version, which is only slightly different:

```
gci -Recurse -Filter "your_folder_name" -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path "C:\"
```

some more info:

```
-Filter "your_folder_name"
```

From documentation: *Filters are more efficient than other parameters. The provider applies filter when the cmdlet gets the objects rather than having PowerShell filter the objects after they're retrieved. The filter string is passed to the .NET API to enumerate files. The API only supports * and ? wildcards.*

```
-Directory
```

Only examine directories, also could be -File

```
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Silences any warnings

```
-Path "C:\"
```

Specifies a path to start searching from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7

Comment: For newbs like my self:      The   -ErrorAction SilintlyContinue     is very important. Some of Windows files are locked. They are locked even if you run as admininistrator.  So if searching for files and folders recursively, it can be problematic and the command just stops with and error message.