# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' error: python3, django, settings.py?

Tags: python, django, windows, postgresql, psycopg2

First of all, I've read I think all the most recent (2019 onwards) posts here about this problem to no avail :(

I've got an up&running default webapp with python3 and django already working with default db.sqlite2. I now neeed to change all that db backend to psql.

So, from these sources:

- https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/
- https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html

I've installed psycopg2-binary, OK.

From this source:

- https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-postgresql-django

I've modified settings.py, DATABASES section, to use psql instead of sqlite. I've tried:

- ```
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
  ```
- ```
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
  ```

And both gives me the error:

```
(env) PS D:\Users\llagos.NB-KEYONE15\Visual Studio projects\ecommerce-psql> python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\llagos.NB-KEYONE15\Visual Studio projects\ecommerce-psql\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
...
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

So, what's wrong with this settings.py file? is this correct? I've tried to google for information but again, no luck. Documentation for psycopg2 doesn't say what to change on settings.py. It just say "install and code", but when using django, there are previous steps, like this settings.py file.

Thanks a lot for any hint!

Regards,

Comment: I'm curious about the output from a `python -m pip freeze` command from within the virtual environment you're using

Comment: `(env) PS D:\Users\llagos.NB-KEYONE15\Visual Studio projects\ecommerce-psql> pip freeze
asgiref==3.3.4
astroid==2.5.6
colorama==0.4.4
Django==3.2.2
isort==5.8.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
mccabe==0.6.1
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6  
pylint==2.8.2
pylint-django==2.4.4    
pylint-plugin-utils==0.6
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
toml==0.10.2
wrapt==1.12.1
(env) PS D:\Users\llagos.NB-KEYONE15\Visual Studio projects\ecommerce-psql>`

Comment: [next one:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63526052/9267296): `gci -Recurse -Filter "env" -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path "D:\Users\llagos.NB-KEYONE15\Visual Studio projects\ecommerce-psql\"`.  I'm trying to exclude multiple envs here. I know it seems stupid, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: also, since you use Visual Studio, are you running from the commandline manually, or relying on VStudio?

Comment: running what? I use the "Integrated Terminal" which gives me an "(env)" prompt, to run stuff like pip, python manage.py, django-admin, etc.

Comment: Just checking. Due to the nature of the error, my first suspicion is you running the code in different context. VStudio allows for different ways to run code, so I'm trying to eliminate possible causes. I'm surprised you're getting this error while `pip freeze` shows it's installed